# Two dimensional dict counter

Tags: python

I need to implement a two dimensional counter in Python from a list. I've seen many solutions however they don't consider initial zero values in order to count. How should I transform this:

```
[
  (P1, B1),
  (P1, B2),
  (P2, B1),
  (P2, B1),
  (P3, B1)
]
```

into this?:

```
{ 
  P1: { 
    B1: 1,
    B2: 1
  },
  P2: {
    B1: 2
  },
  P3: {
    B1: 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
d=defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(int))
for k,v in items:
    d[k][v] += 1
```

I would think should work